# Searchresult sidebar change

Tags: sidebar

So, where is the searchresult page sidebar located?

For example, in the searchresult page, there is "A" sidebar.

However, I want to change it to "B" sidebar.

I looked at `search.php` but could not understand where the sidebar was coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search.php may contain the following code

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

If a name ($name) is specified as an argument then a specialized sidebar sidebar-{name}.php will be included. If sidebar-{name}.php does not exist, then it will fallback to loading sidebar.php.

If the theme contains no sidebar.php file then the sidebar from the default theme will be included

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new sidebar with name `sidebar-search.php` and call it on `search.php` page using

```
<?php get_sidebar('search'); ?>
```